# Something similar to QTableWidget::currentCellChanged in QTableView?

Tags: qt, qt4

I want a signal to be emitted when I either click on a cell or use the arrow keys to navigate to a new cell of a QTableView. When I was using a QTableWidget, I used the currentCellChanged signals. However, I don't see a similar signal in QTableView - is there nothing similar?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use:

- the signal `currentChanged(QModelIndex, QModelIndex)` of the `QItemSelectionModel` instance returned by `QAbstractItemView::selectionModel()`, or
- derive the view and redefine the function `QAbstractItemView::currentChanged(QModelIndex, QModelIndex)`.

PS: When the parameter is a const reference (so not `const` alone, or not `&` alone), you can omit both `const` and `&` in the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros:

```
connect(tableView->selectionModel(), 
        SIGNAL(currentChanged(QModelIndex, QModelIndex)), 
        ...
```

Comment: I used the first method - works like a charm! Thanks! 

 this->connect(this->tableView->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentChanged (const QModelIndex & , const QModelIndex & )), SLOT(SomethingChanged(const QModelIndex & , const QModelIndex & )));

Answer (score 0):

You should reimplement this [method](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qtableview.html#selectionChanged):

```
virtual void selectionChanged ( const QItemSelection & selected, const QItemSelection & deselected )
```

Comment: So to do that I have to use a custom view? Is there no way to do it with the default QTableView?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything as concise as the QTableWidget's currentCellChanged, but QTableView does inherit a few things from [QAbstractItemView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemview.html) that you may be able to use together, specifically the clicked, entered, & pressed signals for mouse input, and the keyPressEvent for keyboard input.  The only real gotcha that I can see is that those depend on you also using the model, as it is all based on the current index of the model being valid.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use event filters and re-implement eventFilter to manage index changes, like this:

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::uiClass)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tableView->installEvenFilter(this);
    connect( ui->tableView, SIGNAL(activated(QModelIndex)), this,SLOT(manageNewIndex(QModelIndex)));

}



bool MyWidget::eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event)
{
    bool retVal = true;
    if(watched == ui->tableView && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QModelIndex index = ui->tableView->currentIndex();
        int row = index.row();
        int col = index.column();

        if(((QKeyEvent*)event)->key() == Qt::Key_Down)
        {
            index = index.sibling(row+1,col);
        }else if(((QKeyEvent*)event)->key() == Qt::Key_Up)
        {
            index = index.sibling(row-1,col);
        }
        if(index.isValid())
        {
            ui->tableView->setCurrentIndex(index);
            manageNewIndex(index);
        }
        retVal = true;
    }
    else
        retVal =  QWidget::eventFilter(watched,event);

    return retVal;
}
```